# Adding Records to Ember Data Store after Ajax Success

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am building a Ember Application where I fetch a feed of Debate objects from an API end point in a route, via the following ajax call:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/api/v2/debate_feed").then(debates => {
      store.push(debates);
    });

  }
});
```

Upon receiving the Debate objects I need to save them to the data store, the problem is I can not access the Ember Data store after the ajax call is complete.  When I try to access the store I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined(…)
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 3):

`store` is not defined in the Route. You can `this.get('store')` to get `store` object. You can try the below code.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel(transition) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/api/v2/debate_feed").then(debates => {
            this.get('store').push(debates);
        });
    },
    model: function() {
        return this.store.peekAll('debate');
    }
});
```

But the preferred approach is,
1.Define debate model [model guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/defining-models/)
2.Define Adapter - JSONAPIAdapter or RESTAdapter.[adapter guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-adapters/)
3.Implement API end point for GET request /debates

then you can just simply say `this.store.findAll('debate')` this will fetch and update it to `store`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({   
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('debate');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `this.store.push(...)`, but you really should implement the ajax call with an adapter! Also notice that the `model` will be empty, because you return nothing. If you want to have the model do `return this.store.push(...)`.